# What do we mean by "impossible" when we say "morality does not require doing the impossible"?

Tags: ethics

"Morality does not require us to do the impossible" has long been an axiom in ethics, but the definition of "impossible" seems to be vague when we examine some extreme cases.

For example, silly mistakes are inevitable for almost everyone. And this implies that making silly mistakes, including those with devastating outcomes, cannot be immoral.

Another example involves racism. If someone has grown up in a racist environment like Nazi Germany, he is very likely to be racist. However, does this imply his attitude towards minorities is morally permitted?

It seems that we cannot simply draw a line between "possible" and "impossible". Can anybody suggest a plausible way out?

Comment: Google has no results for "Morality does not require impossibles", so I find it hard to believe that it's a central axiom in normative ethics. It's also barely grammatical. Can you give an actual quote from some normative ethicists who might phrase it differently?

Comment: Moral impossibility is normally a RELATIVE concept not a pure normative concept. I do know many authors will define moral impossibility differently but the idea generally expresses there is a difficulty in doing the moral act for the person in question. Perhaps he is not phyically capable of doing the proper behavior at the right time & place it is needed. Another point is that the solution may not be a universal: that is, different solutions to the same moral problem at different times or places. Thus we get a subjective morality most of the time & a small percentage of universal solutions.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am a beginner in ethics so I apologize for any incorrect use of terms. I got the idea from Shafer-Landau's The Fundamentals of Ethics, p 95, in a chapter on psychological egoism and its threat to morality. The author states that "we are not required to do the impossible - morality might be pretty demanding at times, but it can't be that demanding".

Comment: @curiousfanni, try typing in moral impossibility into Google and see if there are any hits. Perhaps you typed the wrong thing and saw poor results. Or you can  Try moral impossibility and certainty. If nothing comes up then you can claim the concepts as the OP writes them must be misleading or mistaken.  I googled moral impossibility and saw results.

Comment: @Logikal Sure, I did do that. But try typing what the OP originally wrote and you won't get any results. It's not fair to ask what "we" mean when we say something no one has ever said before. That's why I asked for a direct quote.

Comment: @Logikal Thanks for the information given :) As I don't know the formal name of this statement before, I haven't done any meaningful researches (shows poor results too).

Comment: @curiousdannii [Ought implies can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ought_implies_can) is Kant's formula. It is not entirely uncontroversial, but then nothing in ethics is :) I guess, the question is what types of impossibility then are morally relevant. Physical impossibility gives a free pass, presumably, softer "impossibilities" do not.

Comment: @Conifold Has anybody asserted "can implies ought"? That would seem relevant to the present question and work well with the legal doctrine of: What would be _reasonable_.

Comment: @christo183 That would hardly be very reasonable. Just because one can do (all sorts of bad) things does not mean they ought to do them. Quite the contrary. Indeed, such an ought would be incoherent - one often can do mutually exclusive things in the same situation.

Comment: @Conifold I should probably have specified: _moral goods_ that can be done, ought be done. :)

Comment: @christo183 That is better, but still does not work. Mutually exclusive cans can both be "good". I guess, perfectionism takes the sentiment as far as it can coherently go.

Comment: is this in reference to sartre?

Comment: @christo183 Well Kant distinguishes between perfect and imperfect duties. My understanding is that perfect duties must be done if they can be, whereas imperfect duties are not always compulsory depending on inclination and circumstance.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Possibility and Necessity: An Introduction to Modality](https://1000wordphilosophy.com/2018/12/08/possibility-and-necessity-an-introduction-to-modality/); [Medieval Theories of Modality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-medieval/). But maybe David Hume is right https://www.gutenberg.org/files/9662/9662-h/9662-h.htm  "that these words are absolutely without any meaning, when employed either in philosophical reasonings or common life"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question reminds me of [Sartre](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sartre/#Eth)

> Given the fundamental division of the human situation into facticity
>   and transcendence, bad faith or inauthenticity can assume two
>   principal forms: one that denies the freedom or transcendence
>   component (“I can't do anything about it”) and the other that ignores
>   the factical dimension of every situation (“I can do anything by just
>   wishing it”). The former is the more prevalent form of self deception
>   but the latter is common to people who lack a sense of the real in
>   their lives.

So it seems to be a question about freedom, rather than ethics per se. Someone who is raised by Nazis is as ***free*** to embrace another, less racist, ideology as anyone (Sartre actually says there are no authentically free Nazis).

On the flip side, if we were not able to make mistakes in our potentially moral behaviour then anything would be done just by willing it, and we would not be free and condemned to be free.

So one way to answer the question about what is morally impossible is just to ask what we are free to do.

Comment: +1. This is a sensible and relevant answer. I do not know why it has passed unvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If moral obligations are something humans come up with using rational means, then it makes sense to assume that one should not expect someone to do what is impossible. In this context a moral obligation is analogous to a legal requirement to behave correctly such as when crossing a street with a traffic light. There is no point in legislating behavior that is impossible to perform and there may be circumstances (such as silly decisions) that might excuse one for not behaving correctly if facing a judge and jury.

In that context humans make these moral obligations and humans fulfill them.

However, if one accepts a divine command theory, then humans do not make nor are they alone in fulfilling the moral obligations. All that is required is their obedience. Here is Michael W. Austin's description of it:

> Roughly, Divine Command Theory is the view that morality is somehow dependent upon God, and that moral obligation consists in obedience to God’s commands. Divine Command Theory includes the claim that morality is ultimately based on the commands or character of God, and that the morally right action is the one that God commands or requires. The specific content of these divine commands varies according to the particular religion and the particular views of the individual divine command theorist, but all versions of the theory hold in common the claim that morality and moral obligations ultimately depend on God.

In this context something apparently impossible may be commanded, such as [crossing the Red Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Red_Sea) or treating an enemy with justice and mercy. One can expect God, who gives the commands, will assist one in whatever is required, impossible or not. If a person makes a silly mistake and disobeys there may be ways to obtain forgiveness depending on the particular religion the disobedient person belongs to.

---

Austin, M. W. Divine Command Theory. Retrieved on August 21, 2019 from the *Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy* at https://www.iep.utm.edu/divine-c/

Comment: +1. I see no reason why this answer should have been downvoted.